# A problem in parse certificate with c and openssl

Tags: c, parsing, ssl, openssl

I have a self-signature certificate in X509, and I need to parse the key in this certificate.
I referred to the code of this website: https://zakird.com/2013/10/13/certificate-parsing-with-openssl

And in his parsing part, there are some grammar I can't use.

Like:

```
int pubkey_algonid = OBJ_obj2nid(cert->cert_info->key->algor->algorithm);
```

and:

```
rsa_key = pkey->pkey.rsa;
rsa_e_dec = BN_bn2dec(rsa_key->e);
rsa_n_hex = BN_bn2hex(rsa_key->n);
```

I can't use '->' to refer the struct internal variables. Am I need some files necessary ?

How do I solve it? Or is any other way to get the key in certificate?

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to a website from 2013. *Old* versions of OpenSSL (and SSLeay before it) did allow access to fields in many structures (by declaring them publicly) including `X509` (a typedef for `struct x509_st`) for a cert, and `RSA` for an RSA key(pair). Since 2016 it no longer does; this is called 'opaque' typing and is considered good style for a library which undergoes significant changes from time to time to avoid those changes causing crashes, corruption, and dangerously or even catastrophically wrong results in programs using the library. By making the interface 'opaque' internal changes either still work correctly, or if they can't, give an error message rather than undetected and possibly dangerous nonsense or undefined behavior.

1. Use `X509_get_pubkey` or `X509_get0_pubkey` to get the publickey as an `EVP_PKEY` structure, from which
2. you can get the (already-converted) NID for the algorithm with `EVP_PKEY_id` and
3. assuming the key is RSA get the RSA-specific structure with `EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA` or `EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA`, from which
4. you can get the n and e fields with `RSA_get0_n` and `RSA_get0_e` (or both at once with `RSA_get0_key`).

The difference between get or get1 routines and get0 routines is that the former allocate a copy, which you should free using the appropriate routine when done to avoid a memory leak; the latter (get0) share existing memory and should not be freed, but must not be used if the thing they are sharing is freed or otherwise invalidated.

PS: the fact the cert is self-signed has no effect on parsing the publickey, although it can affect whether a system that does so is secure.
But that's out of scope for SO.